# CSS more short query

Tags: css, css-selectors

For example I have a CSS selector:

```
#spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over span,
#spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over ul,
#spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over ul li { clear:both }
```

Is there a way to write like,

```
(#spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over) span, ul, ul li { clear:both }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use some kind of CSS pre-processors like [Shaun Inman’s CSS server-side pre-processor](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/06/27/css_server_side_pre_processor) to convert this:

```
#spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over {
    span,
    ul,
    ul li { clear:both }
}
```

into this:

```
#spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over span,
#spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over ul,
#spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over ul li { clear:both }
```

But CSS itself has no such syntax.

Answer (score 1):

So what you effectively want is a 'with'/grouping construct?

I don't think CSS can do this directly, but it's certainly would useful.

It probably would not be too difficult to write a basic script that generated the long-hand version from the shorthand.

However, perhaps a more consistent syntax would be:

```
@with( #spotlightPlayer .container .commands.over )
{
    span, ul, ul li { clear:both }
}
```

Whilst longer in this case, it would allow you to add more styles that apply only within that specific block.

***edit:*** or better yet, go with the css pre-processor suggested in the other answer.

Also, regarding Jeremy's answer/comment:
Unless you have (or plan to have) a `.commands.over` item *outside* of the `.container` item, then you can drop the middle part.

When you space-delimit your selectors, it allows for *any* descendant, rather than requiring direct parent/child relationship (like `>` does).

Comment: Yeah, never heard about such preprocessor things, fantasy on rise - if such thing could handle css hacks for all browsers, like meta css language.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [Sass](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/docs/rdoc/classes/Sass.html). It has a lot of helpful little features that let you make your style sheets more declarative than the normal CSS syntax allows. It handles deeply nested tags in a very natural way. In Sass, this would be:

```
#spotlightPlayer .container. commands.over
  span, ul, ul li
    :clear both
```

Comment: Fair enough. I just thought it was worth mentioning since it does make this problem trivial. Some people love it, some not so much. Different strokes and all.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to clean up your CSS, and you don't care about making your HTML messy, apply a class to each `span`, `ul`, and `ul>li` element in the relevant section. You can clear out two extra lines of CSS, but you'll be gaining a lot of weight in HTML cruft. I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: simply speaking, there is no such possibility

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like the problem is with your document structure and not your CSS.  Do you really need that long a list of identifiers to get the specificity that you need? You should only need attributes on your HTML elements such as it takes to describe the data you're displaying.